# PHP Zend Joininner

Tags: php, sql, zend-framework, phpmyadmin, inner-join

I have a SQL statement

```
select a.username 
from friendships f1
inner join friendships f2 on (f1.user = f2.friend and f1.friend = f2.user) 
inner join users a ON (a.user_id = f1.friend) where f1.user = '24'
```

I excuted this query on phpmyadmin and it's OK.

But I don't knoe how to do this query in Zend

```
$select = $this->_db_table->select()
->setIntegrityCheck(false)
->from(array('f1' => 'friendships'), array('u.*'))
->joinInner(array('f2' => 'friendships'), 
            array('f1.user = f2.friend',  'f1.friend = f2.user'))
->joinInner(array('u' => 'users'), array('u.user_id = f1.friend'))
->where('f1.user = ?', $user_id);
```

I use this code but it doesn't work, any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

What version of ZF are you using ? Here is how you would do it in ZF 1.12:

```
$this->_db_table->getAdapter()->select()
    ->from("friendships as f1")
    ->joinInner("friendships as f2", "f1.user = f2.friend AND f1.friend = f2.user")
    ->joinInner("users as a", "a.user_id = f1.friend", array("a.username"))
    ->where("f1.user = ?", $user_id)
    ->query()
    ->fetchAll(); // use ->fetch() if you only want to retrieve one record
```

Read more on in the manual:

Answer (score 0):

What exactly doesn't work? Are you getting a PHP/Zend error or a SQL error?

You can use $select->assemble() to examine the prepared query and compare it against your expectation:

```
echo $select->assemble();
```